# Trying to create a nice character controller?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm kind of new in the 2D environment of Unity.

I'm trying to create a platformer. For now, I have a simple map and my player.

[My simple map and my player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Phz.png)

My player have one script attached :

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float jump;
    public GameObject raycastPoint; // Positioned at 0.01 pixel below the player

    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    private Rigidbody2D body; // Gravity Scale of the Rigidbody2D = 50
    private Animator animator;

    private void Start()
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (horizontal == 1 && spriteRenderer.flipX)
        {
            spriteRenderer.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (horizontal == -1 && !spriteRenderer.flipX)
        {
            spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
        }

        body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, body.velocity.y);

        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontal));

        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (vertical == 1)
        {
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(raycastPoint.transform.position, Vector2.down, 0.01f);

            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                body.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jump));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For now I have achieved the right and left movements.

For the jump, I have a child gameobject just under the player and I'm firing a raycast to the bottom so I can know if my player is grounded or not.

I have two problems.

PROBLEM NUMBER ONE.

Sometimes I feel like my "AddForce" line is executed multiple times my player is jumping really high

[Problem number one image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U48k.png)

PROBLEM NUMBER TWO.

When I'm jumping to the left or right wall, if I keep pressing the left or right key my player is not falling anymore and stay against the wall.

[Problem number two image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbriG.png)

I tried to put my code into the FixedUpdate method (I know it's better) but I had the same results.

And I tried to set the Collision Detection on Continuous but I had the same results.

Comment: Regarding your problem number two: That's a common issue. The force you apply towards the wall is greater than the gravity that is pulling the player down. Try searching for _2D Platformer, player is sticking to walls_ and see if you find anything to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your first problem :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider2D))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]

public class Player_Controller : MonoBehaviour {
private Rigidbody2D body;
private bool canJump, facingRight;
private Animator anim;
[SerializeField]
private float moveSpeed, jumpForce;

void Start () 
{
    SetStartValues();
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontal));
    Flip(horizontal);
    Move(horizontal);
    Jump();
}

private void SetStartValues()
{
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    canJump = true;
    facingRight = true;
}

private void Jump()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && canJump)
    {
        body.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
        canJump = false;
    }
}

private void Move(float x)
{
    body.velocity = new Vector2(x * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, body.velocity.y);
}

private void Flip(float x)
{
    if (x > 0 && !facingRight|| x < 0 && facingRight)
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x * -1, transform.localScale.y) ;
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
    {
        canJump = true;
    }
}
}
```

And don't forget to put the "Ground" tag on your ground object.